# Find the min value in a coulumn from many files and print in another file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file1 which looks like this

```
25       104.601  0.5 
24.8488  104      0.5 
24.5341  103      0.5 
24.1844  102      0.5 
24.1568  101      0.5 
24.1568  100      0.5 
24.1844  99       0.5 
24.5341  98       0.5
```

I need to find the min value from column 1 and print it in another file_NEW

Now I need to repeat the above for different files and find the min for at least 100 files ..

So that I shall have a final output in file_NEW something like this

```
24.1568
23.3254 (from file2)
22.312  (from file3)
.....
```

Here, file2 and file3 have similar datasets as file1. All the input files have same name patterns like file*.txt and are in the same directory

Can anyone suggest how to do this with awk or sed?

Thanks

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Do you need these `from file3`, `from file2` in `file_NEW`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk edited. Only min value from Col1 from all files into file_NEW

Comment: Can any of the input files be empty? If so, how should they be handled? Can any of the $1 values be negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `sed` version

```
find . -name "file*" -exec sh -c '
   echo $(sort -nk1 "$1"  | sed -n "1{s/ .*//p}" )" (from "${1##*/}")" ' sh {} \; | sort -nk1 > output.txt; cat output.txt
```

`sort`ing the output file if needed and adding the filenames

Answer (score 2):

To Find the Minimimum Value we can use below command

Use below command on each file

```
awk 'NR==1{sum=$1}($1 < sum){sum=$1}END{print sum}'  filename >> outputfile
```

Tested and worked fine

Comment: +1 but I'd suggest changing the variable name to something other than `sum` (perhaps `min`?). FWIW if you have GNU awk (`gawk`) you could change `NR==1` to `FNR==1` and `END` to `ENDFILE` to allow it to be run on multiple files at once.

Comment: Thanks for input

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $1 "\t(from " FILENAME ")"}' file* | sort -k1,1n | awk -F'\t' '!seen[$2]++'
```

The above will work robustly and efficiently on all of your input files at once using standard UNIX tools, e.g.:

```
$ cat file1
25       104.601  0.5
24.8488  104      0.5
24.5341  103      0.5
24.1844  102      0.5
24.1568  101      0.5
24.1568  100      0.5
24.1844  99       0.5
24.5341  98       0.5

$ cat file2
75       104.601  0.5
74.8488  104      0.5
74.5341  103      0.5
74.1844  102      0.5
74.1568  101      0.5
74.1568  100      0.5
74.1844  99       0.5
74.5341  98       0.5

$ awk '{print $1 "\t(from " FILENAME ")"}' file{1,2} | sort -k1,1n | awk -F'\t' '!seen[$2]++'
24.1568 (from file1)
74.1568 (from file2)
```

but assumes none of your file names contain tab or newline characters. If they do contain tabs it's a simple tweak to handle them:

```
awk '{print $1 "\t(from " FILENAME ")"}' file* |
sort -k1,1n |
awk '{f=$0; sub(/[^\t]*\t/,"",f)} !seen[f]++'
```

but if they also contain newlines, then you'd need GNU tools to accommodate `\0` (NUL) terminators:

```
awk -v ORS='\0' '{print $1 "\t(from " FILENAME ")"}' file* |
sort -z -k1,1n |
awk -v RS='\0' '{f=$0; sub(/[^\t]*\t/,"",f)} !seen[f]++'
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want this on each file:

```
awk 'NF' FILE | sort -n -k1 - | awk 'NR==1{print $1}' >> file_NEW
```

The initial `awk 'NF' FILE` is needed in case you had empty blank
lines in input files. You didn't specify if you want to run this command on all files in a
given directory recursively or non-recursively or only on some files
with specific patterns in their names.  Anyway, you can use `find` to
do that:

```
find . -name "FILE*" -exec sh -c 'awk "NF" FILE | sort -n -k1 - | awk "NR==1{print \$1}" >> file_NEW' sh {} \;
```

In this case the above command is run on all files in the given
directory whose name starts with `FILE`.

Also notice that this will not necessarily give you sorted list in
output `file_NEW` because `find` will blindly run everything after `-exec`
on each file it finds.